# Can a sql command in php be set from pieces of other variables with "." connector?

Tags: php, sql

I´m STILL LEARNING, currently sql and I want to ask, if this piece if code is valid. I´m not sure, if i can build a mysql command like I did here. I know, It´s terrible, but that´s why I´m asking . 
Here I sent some variables via post method and I want to insert them into the table, but I don´t know how to include these variables. 
There must be some possibilities, but maybe this is valid.

```
$m = "', '";
//$m for the spacing 
$sql = "INSERT INTO Log (Ip, Email, Name) VALUES ('" . $ip . $m . $email . $m . $name . "');";
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: If you want to pass data into MySQL you need to prepare and bind. You should not put PHP variables in the SQL. Check my links above.

Comment: @Dharman  "you should not PHP variable in the sql" how?? You say use PDO and this for MySQL connection within query but php still in the action.. what you mean about this?

Comment: You can use either PDO or MySQLi. I do not know which one you are trying to use at the moment. Both will work for MySQL and PDO has a simpler syntax. In your example you are putting `$email` or `$name` in the query, but this is your data so it should be separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal answer on your question: Yes, you could. Should you (do it like you say in your example)? NO!
It is dangerous to put userinput directly into sql ([sql injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) ect.).
Ignoring that, you are going into the good direction:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Log (Ip, Email, Name) VALUES ($ip, $Email, $Name);";
```

If you don't want your data corrupted use a PDO connection and the prepare statement as below:

```
    $Ip = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Ip"]); //converts every special character
    $Email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Email"]);
    $Name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Name"]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Log (Ip, Email, Name) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"; // the questionmark represent the variable in the array (order matters)

    try {
        $stmt = $PDOconnection->prepare($sql); //prepare DB
        $stmt->execute(array($Ip, $Email, $Name)); // execute sql
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // fetch feedback into an array
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); //show the error
    }
```

Or to be even more secure:

```
$stmt = $PDOconnection->prepare('INSERT INTO Log (Ip, Email, Name) VALUES (:ip, :Email, :Name;)';
$stmt->execute( array('Ip' => $Ip, 'Email' => $Email, 'Name' => $Name));
```

And if you want to go pro level you could use [stored procedures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).